# Bash for loop ends after 300 loops?

Tags: bash, shell

I have a very interesting problem, in my bash script below, the for loop somehow halts always after 300 loops ( and I sometimes need it to perform over 600 ).

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in `seq $1 $2`;
do

composite $i".png" $i"_temp.png" $i"_out.png"

done
```

I had no trouble running the same command looped in other languages with over 300 loops. I don't know what happens with bash.

Also, I noticed that after the 300th loop, the script doesn't exit, but instead "pauses".

I'm currently using a workaround for this problem by running the script from 1 to 250, then from 251 to 500, etc.

Comment: what's the range you are using? this should work with a couple-of-digit numbers

Comment: 1 - 500+ (never above 700 tho)

Comment: can't provoke the error in any way. What OS are you running? What does `file your_script.sh` output? Bash-version? How do you call the script ? If you change the shebang to `#!/bin/bash -x` what do you get when the script halts?

Comment: GNU bash, version 4.1.2(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu), /opt/MyApp/MyApp_ScriptOne.sh: Bourne-Again shell script text executable

Comment: calling it using: ./MyApp_ScriptOne.sh 1 500

Comment: ok, tested upto 100000 without any problems. And the output with debugginfo?

Comment: ...and you don't have a `&` after the `composite` command? meaning that you spawning a huge amount of processes...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I wondered if this might be a limit on the amount of output that can be substituted in backticks, but I can't reproduce that on my Linux system, and it's surprising that you apparently don't see any error message.  However, something you could try as an alternative to your current script is to still use `seq` but pass its results into a `while read` loop, which would avoid the substitution:

```
seq $1 $2 | while read i
do
    composite $i".png" $i"_temp.png" $i"_out.png"
done
```

Comment: I applied your modification to my script, running it now, it's a long script so it will take it 20 mins to complete and see if that one works.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use a while loop?

```
i=0
while [ $i -le $1 ]
    do 
        composite $i".png" $i"_temp.png" $i"_out.png"
        i=$((i + 1))
    done
```

Comment: fixed that for you -- `[` is actually a command, not a piece of syntax. Therefore it needs whitespace before and after. The last argument to the `[` command must be `]`. Also, you can not have whitespace around the `=` in an assignment.

Answer (score 0):

No need to use external commands

```
for ((i=$1; i<=$2 ;i++))
do
  composite "${i}.png" "${i}_temp.png" "${i}_out.png"
done
```